# RxJava2 : 2 separate observerable output and and merge output of same observables differ

Tags: rx-java2

Snippet1 , I can see the sysout from both subscribers.
Snippet2 , I dont see output from the second observable.
Why is the merge not working for me?

Snippet1

```
x = createQ2Flowable().subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .filter(predicate -> !predicate.toString().contains("<log realm=\"\""))
        .subscribe(onNext -> System.out.println("Q2->" + onNext));

y = createMetricsFlowable().subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
        .observeOn(Schedulers.io())
        .subscribe(onNext -> System.out.println("metrics->" + onNext));
```

Snippet2

```
createQ2Flowable().mergeWith(createMetricsFlowable())
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())
.subscribe(onNext -> System.out.println(onNext));
```

[edit]: Added flowable creators

```
private Flowable<String> createMetricsFlowable() {
    return Flowable.create(source -> {
        Space sp = SpaceFactory.getSpace("rxObservableFeeder");
        while (running()) {
            String line = (String) sp.in("RXTmFeeder");
            source.onNext(line);
        }

    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);

}

private Flowable<String> createQ2Flowable() {
    return Flowable.create(source -> {
        Space sp = SpaceFactory.getSpace("LoggerSpace");
        while (running()) {
            LogEvent line = (LogEvent) sp.in("rxLoggingKey");
            source.onNext(line.toString());

        }

    }, BackpressureStrategy.BUFFER);

}
```

Comment: Please provide the implementation of those `createX()` `Flowable`s. Also try `createQ2Flowable().subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()).mergeWith(createMetricsFlowable().subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation()))` in Snippet2.

Comment: I tried your recommendation, it worked. Now I need to know why it happened. Thank you.

Comment: I am also getting incomplete sysouts when I add a observeOn just before the subscribe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the comments:

try

```
createQ2Flowable()
.subscribeOn(Schedulers.computation())      // <-------------------------
.mer‌​geWith(createMetrics‌​Flowable()
    .subscribe‌​On(Schedulers.comput‌​ation())  // <-------------------------
)
```

> Now I need to know why it happened

Given the detailed implementation, you have two synchronous `Flowable`s. When you merge them, the first `Flowable` is subscribed to and starts emitting immediately and never giving back the control to `mergeWith`, therefore the second `Flowable` is never subscribed to.

The `subscribeOn` after `mergeWith` is not equivalent to the solution provided above. You have to explicitly have both `Flowable`s subscribed on a background thread so `mergeWith` can subscribe to the second `Flowable` after now that the synchronous looping has been moved off from the thread the `mergeWith` uses for subscribing to its sources.

Comment: Perfect , each flowable with its own subscribeOn makes sense. The observeOn problem before the subscribe also got solved with this. I had also incorrectly place the second subscribeOn after the mergewith, instead of on the createMetrics‌​Flowable(), braketting error. Thank you for assisting in resolving this.